# changing extensions of all images in a folder with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to convert the image formats of all images in a folder using tkinter. all extensions I want in a combobox but I don't know why this code doesn't work .no error is displayed.

````
from tkinter import  filedialog, StringVar
from tkinter import ttk
root=tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
#defining functions
def get_folder():
    global folder_path
    folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir='./', title="Select Folder")
    print(folder_path)

def get_extension():
    change_to = com.get()
    change_from = "py"
    files=os.listdir(folder_path)

    for file in files:
        if (".%s"%change_from) in file:
            newfile=file.replace((".%s"%change_from),".%s"%change_to)
            os.rename((folder_path+'/'+file),(folder_path+'/'+newfile))
#defining widgets for frames
folder_label = tkinter.Label(from_frame)
browse_button = tkinter.Button(from_frame, text="Browse", command=get_folder)

change_button = tkinter.Button(button_frame, text="Change Extension", command=get_extension)
change_button.pack()

#defining combobox
com = StringVar()
list_combo = ['.png','.jpg','.jpeg', '.svg', '.tif','.bmp','.gif','ppm']
combox = ttk.Combobox(root, width = 25, font = 'arial 19 bold', value = list_combo, state = 'r', textvariable = com)
combox.place(x= 190, y= 190)
combox.set('select type')
root.configure(bg = 'coral1')

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Why would you want to change the extension of a file from `.py` to an image extension? You wouldn't be able to open the image. Also what do you mean by *this code doesn't work*? What does it do? Have you tried printing `folder_path+'/'+file` and `folder_path+'/'+newfile` before the `os.rename`?

Comment: No, I  want to change all image i have in a folder to another extention

Comment: there is a solution?

Comment: if You ask whether it is possible then the answer if in most cases (99.9%): yes, it is possible, which also means that there is a solution. btw wouldn't this impact some of the formats and convert them incorrectly?

Comment: why is `change_from = 'py'`? You understand right that will definitely change all `.py` files right?

Comment: I don't want to change from ' .py'.
I need  to change all folder of images from ('.png','.jpg','.jpeg', '.svg', '.tif','.bmp','.gif','ppm') to one format  that I select in combobox

Comment: If you don't want to change from '.py', why do you have `change_from = "py"` in your code?

Comment: Just changing the file extension of an image file does not actually change the format of the image file.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what You want:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, StringVar, Frame
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import os


def convert_extensions():
    path = dir_lbl.cget('text')
    from_ = from_var.get()
    to_ = to_var.get()
    files_from = [f'{path}/{file}' for file in os.listdir(path) if file.split('.')[-1] == from_]
    files_to = ['.'.join(file.split('.')[:-1]) + '.' + file.split('.')[-1].replace(from_, to_) for file in files_from]

    for from_file, to_file in zip(files_from, files_to):
        os.rename(from_file, to_file)
        print(f'{"-" * 100}\n'
              f'{"From:": <10} {from_file}\n'
              f'{"To:": <10} {to_file}\n')


root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x200')

Button(root, text='Choose Directory', command=lambda: dir_lbl.config(text=askdirectory())).pack(pady=5)
dir_lbl = Label(root, text='')
dir_lbl.pack(pady=5)

options_frame = Frame(root)
options_frame.pack(pady=5)

from_var = StringVar(value='Convert from')
list_combo = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'svg', 'tif', 'bmp', 'gif', 'ppm']
Combobox(options_frame, value=list_combo,
         textvariable=from_var, state='r').pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5)

to_var = StringVar(value='Convert to')
Combobox(options_frame, value=list_combo,
         textvariable=to_var, state='r').pack(side='left', padx=5, pady=5)

Button(root, text='Convert', command=convert_extensions).pack(pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

This however allows more control in that You can choose both the extension to convert and to which one convert.

This is pretty basic so if You have any questions, ask. I will probably add a detailed explanation later but for now this is all I can do. Oh and btw that three line print function is not necessary at all and it probably should be made to display that in tkinter window or sth but otherwise it can be removed.

Comment: I need choose only the extension 'Convert to' for converting all image extensions to a specific extension(that I select in combobox). How can I do this?

Comment: @MehdiWahib change `file.split('.')[-1] == from_` to `file.split('.')[-1] in list_combo` and this: `'.'.join(file.split('.')[:-1]) + '.' + file.split('.')[-1].replace(from_, to_)` to this: `'.'.join(file.split('.')[:-1]) + f'.{to_}'` then You can delete everything related to the other combobox and it should work